# How to filter articles that have image

Tags: views, 6, media

In Views block, how do I display the articles that only have image?

How to filter it?

[image]

Update question:

1） Under **Filters**, add **Content: Image (field_image) - list**.

2)  Choose **False** option.

3)  Preview of block disappear.

How do I fix it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You add a filter criteria that checks the image's file id (fid):

```
Content: Image (field_image:fid)

Operator: Is not empty (NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Under "Filters", there are only have **Content: Image (field_image) - delta** and **Content: Image (field_image) - list**.  There are no **fid**. How do I solve it?

Comment: Perhaps you need to add [File Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity) module.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a filter

   [image]
2. Choose your image field (fid)

   [image]
3. Set it to 'Is not empty'

   [image]

Comment: I am using Drupal 6. Under "Filters", there are only have **Content: Image (field_image) - delta** and **Content: Image (field_image) - list**.  There are no **fid**. How do I solve it?

Comment: Try using `Content: Image (field_image) - list` and setting that to 'not empty'.

Comment: I select **Content: Image (field_image) - list**. The only option is **True** or **False**. (This item is currently exposed. If you hide it, users will not be able to change the filter as they view it. ）

Comment: If click **"expose"**, there are **Filter identifier:** , **Label:** , **Optional** and **Remember**.

Comment: Doesn't need to be exposed, try setting it to false, see what it does.

Comment: I set it to **False**, the block has been disappear. Nothing shown.

Comment: It is a while since I've used 6.  Maybe it would help if you updated your question with a screenshot of the filter you're trying to create.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

[image: views drupal not image]

> **create view and use these filters ,it will show nodes that only have
>   image not body**